# Workflow connections are displaying oddly

Tags: xaml, .net-4.0, workflow-foundation-4, designer

Hi I'm creating a Workflow with C# WWF 4.0 and I'm experiencing some problems:

My test code is:

```
Flowchart flow = new Flowchart
{
    DisplayName = "Test",
    StartNode = new FlowSwitch<String> { Expression = "[prop1]" },
    Variables = { new Variable<String> { Name = "prop1" } },
};
FlowNode MySwitch = flow.StartNode;
flow.Nodes.Add(MySwitch);
```

I save it:

```
StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(@"../../test.xaml");
var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(sw,
    new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true, OmitXmlDeclaration = false });
    using (xmlWriter)
    {
        var xamlXmlWriter = new XamlXmlWriter(xmlWriter, new XamlSchemaContext());
        using (xamlXmlWriter)
        {
            XamlWriter xamlWriter = ActivityXamlServices.CreateBuilderWriter(xamlXmlWriter);
            using (xamlWriter)
            {
                var activityBuilder = new ActivityBuilder { Name = "Test", Implementation = Workflow };
                XamlServices.Save(xamlWriter, activityBuilder);
            }
        }
    }
    sw.Close();
```

and then I get this XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Activity x:Class="Test" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/activities" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <Flowchart DisplayName="Test">
    <Flowchart.Variables>
      <Variable x:TypeArguments="x:String" Name="prop1" />
    </Flowchart.Variables>
    <Flowchart.StartNode>
      <x:Reference>__ReferenceID0</x:Reference>
    </Flowchart.StartNode>
    <FlowSwitch x:TypeArguments="x:String" x:Name="__ReferenceID0" Expression="[prop1]" />
  </Flowchart>
</Activity>
```

and when I load it in Visual Studio I get this Workflow:

[image: My Workflow]

I think this is wrong because the arc starting from "Start" node should be under  the box and not over!

If I add other steps they all connect using only the over position.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Honestly, you don't need to put tags in your title.  You already have them *where they belong*.  Also, I don't think you're doing anything wrong; the editor is just not making good decisions on where to draw the connecting lines.  Just open up a connect and ask them to fix their layout logic.

Answer (score 0):

The editor is just using it's default values when you open the activity's XAML for the first time, because it doesn't have a view state available.

If you edit it through the designer, view state properties (i.e. designer's size, position, etc.) are added to the XAML:

```
<Activity mc:Ignorable="sap" x:Class="Test" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="654,676" mva:VisualBasic.Settings="Assembly references and imported namespaces serialized as XML namespaces" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/activities" xmlns:av="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:mva="clr-namespace:Microsoft.VisualBasic.Activities;assembly=System.Activities" xmlns:sad="clr-namespace:System.Activities.Debugger;assembly=System.Activities" xmlns:sap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/activities/presentation" xmlns:scg="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <Flowchart DisplayName="Test" sad:XamlDebuggerXmlReader.FileName="c:\users\jp-correia\desktop\WorkflowConsoleApplication1\WorkflowConsoleApplication1\test.xaml" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="614,636" mva:VisualBasic.Settings="Assembly references and imported namespaces serialized as XML namespaces">
    <Flowchart.Variables>
      <Variable x:TypeArguments="x:String" Name="prop1" />
    </Flowchart.Variables>
    <sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
      <scg:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object">
        <x:Boolean x:Key="IsExpanded">False</x:Boolean>
        <av:Point x:Key="ShapeLocation">240,72.5</av:Point>
        <av:Size x:Key="ShapeSize">60,75</av:Size>
        <av:PointCollection x:Key="ConnectorLocation">240,110 150,110 150,192.5</av:PointCollection>
      </scg:Dictionary>
    </sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
    <Flowchart.StartNode>
      <FlowSwitch x:TypeArguments="x:String" x:Name="__ReferenceID0" Expression="%[prop1]" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="60,75">
        <sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
          <scg:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object">
            <av:Point x:Key="ShapeLocation">120,192.5</av:Point>
            <av:Size x:Key="ShapeSize">60,75</av:Size>
          </scg:Dictionary>
        </sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
      </FlowSwitch>
    </Flowchart.StartNode>
    <x:Reference>__ReferenceID0</x:Reference>
  </Flowchart>
</Activity>
```

Maybe you can work up something with [WorkflowViewStateService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.presentation.view.workflowviewstateservice.aspx) directly but it will get you in troubles for sure. I would avoid messing with it.

What is your case-scenario? Maybe you should be using a rehosted designer for whatever you're trying to accomplish.